# write an indent text in html page

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML and I want to show this text(except those red underlines) on my HTML page, I have studied all of the HTML tags and wrote this code. but still, it's not like the text :( if anyone could, please help me fix it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Brandning</h2>
  <p>
    <big>I build and activate brands through cultural insigh & strategic vision.</big>
  </p>
  <p>
    <big>See more products</big>
  </p>
  <footer>
    <p>© 2020 Cris. All rights reserved</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

[this a demo of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz7ep.png)

Comment: Please note the `big` tag is [obsolete and should not be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/big) . Don't use HTML to style your document, that is the job of CSS (HTML does provide a foundation and play a part)

Comment: You could use the `<pre></pre>` tag for preformatted text, but HTML does not dictate style. Use CSS for that. You should know that one or more white spaces in HTML shows up as only a single white space. Whether the Browser takes that space off at the very begging of a tags textContent depends on the Browser. For this reason I actually do `*{ font-size:0; }` in CSS, then individually assign `font-size` more directly. You could indent like `.indent{ margin-left:10px; }` then just add `class='indent'` to your HTML tags. Just comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add styling to the text, you'll need to use CSS on top of HTML.
We can do this by adding a css file or using in-line styling like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="margin-left:50px;">
    <h2>Brandning</h2>
    <p>
      <big>I build and activate brands through cultural insigh & strategic vision.</big>
    </p>
    <p>
      <big>See more products</big>
    </p>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>© 2020 Cris. All rights reserved</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

We created a div container and set the left margin to 50px which gives the text the indent you want

Comment: thanks, i fixed it. and how about that sticked together title and content? when i execute my code, they are not sticked and have some distance

Comment: You'll want to set the header margin to none `<h2 style="margin:0px;">Brandning</h2>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only `html`, you can cover the `indented` texts using `<blockquote>` tag as follows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <blockquote>
    <h2>Brandning</h2>
    <p>
      <big>I build and activate brands through cultural insigh & strategic vision.</big>
    </p>
    <p>
      <big>See more products</big>
    </p>
  </blockquote>
  <footer>
    <p>© 2020 Cris. All rights reserved</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yes, i prefer use html for now, i tried it, thank u

Comment: Can you pls approve my answer if that's what you were looking for?